# External load balancer not receiving request

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I have two private application subnets. Route table of those subnets are set to send external traffic to the inside interface of my firewall, which lies in another subnet.

For some reason, I also want my application servers to accept traffic from internet facing load balancer. 
However,  both of these conditions do not work together.

When I set the routing rule to forward external packets my external load balancer stops responding. When I remove that rule it works fine.
When I tcpdump, I can't see any traffic at all with routing rule set. 
My load balancer lies in two availability zones, and I can see that there are two network interfaces created for it. Both interfaces have public ip address.

As the interfaces have public ip's associated, I don't think that there should be any barrier as the packet should be forwarded to the internet directly,  and should not go back to the router to be effected by routing rule.

Also if this is the case, then at least I should see incoming traffic on the server.
I don't know much about networking.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the interfaces have public ip's associated, I don't think that there should be any barrier as the packet should be forwarded to the internet directly, and should not go back to the router to be effected by routing rule.

Incorrect.  The fact that the interfaces have public IP addresses is exactly why they need to be on **public** subnets (definition: route table sends traffic to the Internet Gateway).  The route table is always applied, whether there are public IP addresses or not.

> Also if this is the case, then at least I should see incoming traffic on the server.

No, you wouldn't.  The balancer can't negotiate the incoming TCP connections from external clients unless its responses can reach them via its associated subnets' route tables.  Absent any successful connections, the balancer has no traffic to send to the instances.

Elastic Load Balancers (classic and ALB) need to be on public subnets.  The instances should be on the private subnets as you described.  Having balancers and instances on different subnets from each other is standard configurarion.